# Retrieve number after point in BigDecimal number without RoundingMode

Tags: java, bigdecimal

how to keep only 3 value after point in BigDecimal ?

i found a solution but it requirt a RoundingMode

```
    BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5649);
    System.out.println(d.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE));
    System.out.println(d.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1), 3, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

i want to keep a number exact without rounding.

Comment: How would you expect it to represent (say) "1 divided by 3" without rounding?

Comment: I can't easily try your example here, but why not just answer my question? "Keeping a number exact" and "only keeping 3 decimal places" are contradictory requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Just use setScale and RoundingMode.DOWN

> Rounding mode to round towards zero. Never increments the digit prior
>   to a discarded fraction (i.e., truncates).

for example

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.5649).setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN)
```

Comment: With RoundingMode.DOWN it gives for example :
5.5 --> 5

Comment: Thanks Luca, but you are sure that RoundingMode.DOWN don't take any rounding ? it gives a number exact ?

Comment: I don't understand what "exact" means. RoundingMode.DOWN just truncates unwanted decimals.

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal isn't intended to be used with such limitations. Only ever wanting 3 decimals is a strange requirement. Maybe you only want to present 3 decimals to the users?

If so I suggest using: `java.text.DecimalFormat`

If you really want to make sure that you never do calculations with higher precission than 3 decimals I suggest making your own reprensentation/class. Internally you hold the value as a `long` (or appropriate class/primitive) but at a value 1000 times the actual value. All calculations are done with the internal reprensentation and when asked for a value, divide the internal value with 1000.0d and convert to `double` (or appropriate) and return.

Comment: i given in example a double but in my program i have a BigDecimal number and some time this number it equals double !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that sentence. You need to consider the constradiction in terms of "keeping a number exact without rounding" and "keep only 3 value after point", the latter I interpret as not having higher precission than 1/1000.

Comment: Yes but not only 1/1000 , if i have a number 0.98987656535353535364747484848484 ... i keep X value after point :) but "a number exact" not rounding

Comment: What is "X"? Didn't you say 3 earlier?

Comment: it's not problem X = 3 or 20, my problem is how can i keep 3 number after point whitout Rounding :) ... it's just this ;)

Comment: Are you trolling? If there are more than 3 digits after the point, and you only want to keep 3 of thoose then you want to do some rounding - it is the definition of rounding. Maybe you want some special case of rounding, as in always round up, or just discard all the other digits. It is still rounding. And it is most definitely not "exact" since you are lowering the exactness.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `double` for this.

```
double d = 0.5649;
d = (long) (d * 1000) / 1000.0; // round down.
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
0.564
```

or

```
d = (long) (d * 1000 + 0.5) / 1000.0; // round half up.
```